# Django does not renders AngularJS resource

Tags: django, api, angularjs, tastypie

I'm retrieving data django tastypie using AngularJS $resource service, but on the html page I'm not getting except li buttons equals to the returned objects, to be more specific I have just blank spaces and I cannot figure out why because verbatim tag is added.

Here is my code:

## app file

```
var subtitlesApp = angular.module('subtitlesApp', ['ngResource']);

subtitlesApp.controller('SubtitleController', 
function SubtitleController($scope, subtitleData) {
$scope.subtitles = subtitleData.query();
console.log($scope.subtitles);

subtitlesApp.factory('subtitleData', function ($resource) {

return $resource('/api/v1/entry/:id/?format=json', {id:'@id'}, {
    query: {method:'GET', isArray:false}
});
});
```

## html file.

```
<div ng-controller="SubtitleController">
<li ng-repeat="subtitle in subtitles.objects"></li>
<h2> {% verbatim %} {{subtitle.id}} {% endverbatim %}</h2>

</div>
```

## console

```
Resource
meta: Object
objects: Array[4]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Resource
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: I see somewhere to use django with Angular.js, a good idea is to put partials (template views for angular) in a static directory, so django will render it without any change. (and you don't need to use verbatim tag)

Comment: I know about that and if I won't fix this situation I will choose that way, but nevertheless if the $resource return a single objects django renders it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your angular template, not Django. `subtitle` is only in scope within the `ng.repeat`, which is party of the `li` element - but you close the `li` immediately after opening it. The `h2` is not part of that scope.

The Angular-batarang Chrome extension can help you debug issues with scopes like this.